# Psalm: Handle method that returns multiple types

Tags: php, symfony-console, psalm-php

**EDIT** This is a Psalm thing, not a PHP MD thing.

I am writing a Symfony console command. In its `execute` method I retrieve argument with the `$input->getArgument('argument_name')` method. And I pass this value to a service, which expects this value to be of string type.

The overall code:

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (is_string($input->getArgument('identifier'))) {
            $identifier = $input->getArgument('identifier');
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
        if ($input->getArgument('mode') === "vehicle") {
            $this->vehicleService->getVehicleInfo($identifier);
            return null;
        }
        if ($input->getArgument('mode') === "company") {
            $this->vehicleService->getCompanyVehiclesInfo($identifier);
            return null;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

<s>PHP MD</s> Psalm doesn't see that I have confirmed that `$identifier` is a string before passing it as an argument to one of `vehicleService` methods and throws me the `PossiblyInvalidArgument` error, because `Argument 1 ... expects string, possibly different type array<array-key, string>|null|string provided`.

How can I ensure PHP MD that this is a string?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting `$identifier` to string, passing it as `(string)$identifier`, or assigning it as `$identifier = (string)$input->getArgument('identifier');`?

Comment: PHP MD will say that it is impossible to cast a possible array variable to a string :(

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after few tries. I needed to put everything inside the `if (is_string(...))` check:

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $identifier = $input->getArgument('identifier');
        if (is_string($identifier)) {
            if ($input->getArgument('mode') === "vehicle") {
                $this->vehicleService->getVehicleInfo($identifier);
                return null;
            }
            if ($input->getArgument('mode') === "company") {
                $this->vehicleService->getCompanyVehiclesInfo($identifier);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of march, the [Symfony Psalm Plugin](https://github.com/psalm/psalm-plugin-symfony) handles arguments and options properly. No need for workarounds anymore :)